# This app can't run on your PC, to find a version of your PC check with the software publisher

Tags: java

when I am trying to install jdk(set up file) on my system(windows 8) I am getting the following error,
This app can't run on your PC, to find a version of your PC check with the software publisher.
Please someone help me to solve this problem. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe a 32 bit - 64 bit mismatch?

Comment: Didn't know what this error meant so I googled it. http://superuser.com/questions/518289/this-app-cant-run-on-your-pc-is-displayed-when-running-a-program  You could learn how to use google one day. ;)

Comment: I tried with both X86 and x64 version, but it showing the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use jdk7 for windows8

this link will help you
http://java-buddy.blogspot.in/2012/01/install-jdk-7-on-windows-8.html

Comment: I am already followed the same steps, but while executing the downloaded file I am getting the above error......